# Working with arrays and bitwise operators in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

i am having some troubles dealing with arrays and bitwise operators...

Thats the problem: I have an array typed as CheckBox, in this array i have 3 checkbox, one for each option i have (pvrtc, dtc1, dtx15), and then i have the option: only one checkbox true, or all true. Now i want to use bitwise operators for my states.

thats what i get untill now:

```
// thats my class with the possible states like consts
public class CompressionCombinations {

public static const selectedPvrtc:uint = 1<<0;

public static const selectedEtc1:uint = 1<<1;

public static const selectedDxt15:uint = 1<<2;

public static const selectedPvrtcEtc1Dxt15:uint = selectedPvrtc && selectedEtc1 && 
selectedDxt15;
// thats mean: selectedPvrtc = checkbox1 true, checkbox2 false, checkbox3 false.

//now my main class

//attributing my checkboxes into array

_combinationArray = new Array();
_combinationArray[0] = _checkBoxPvrtc;
_combinationArray[1] = _checkBoxEtc1;
_combinationArray[2] = _checkBoxDxt15;

// a function that do the maths

if((bin=uint(_combinationArray[0].selected + _combinationArray[1].selected +
_combinationArray[2].selected)) == CompressionCombinations.selectedPvrtc){

_argNativeProcess = new String("p");
_nativeProcess.setupAndLaunch(_inputNativeProcess, _outputNativeProcess,  
_argNativeProcess, this);
_msgSuccessErrorTextField.text = "Converting...";
}
else{
trace("not working");
}
```

Thats the problem, i cannot apply the bitwise opperation in it... dont know how to use or construct a function to do it. I know how to do it without bitwise operators, but i want with bitwise operation for future new releases...

Any ideas ? Suggestions in how to solve that?

Comment: why use bitwise at all trace((uint(true)+uint(true)+uint(false))>1)

Comment: sry, i didnt understand... that function its not correct, i just tryied to do something... i want to compare the result of the 3 checkboxes with my consts... the cost 'public static const selectedPvrtc:uint = 1<<0;' means that checkboxes1 selected = true and the rest its false.

Comment: what i want to do is... `if(selectedPvrtc){ Do something }; if(selectedEtc1){ Do something }; if(selectedDxt15){ Do something }`

Comment: My point is you do not need the bitwise ops. As I shown above you can solve your issue by testing if the total checked is greater than 1

Comment: Ah i just saw the statement you made about wanting it in bitwise.

Comment: the problem is that i need to know wich checkbox is selected... thats why i created the const's ... each const variable means a state. const1 means - checkbox1 true, checkbox2 false, checkbox3 false; const2 means - checkbox1 false, checkbox2 true, checkbox3 false; const3 means - checkbox1 false, checkbox2 false, checkbox3 true. ... So if i try the first option, my output will be 1 (check1 = 1, check2 = 0, check3 = 0) and 1 its equal a 1<<0 - thats my firs const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectedPvrtc:uint = 1;
var selectedEtc1:uint = 2;
var selectedDxt15:uint = 4;

var _combinationArray :Array = new Array();
_combinationArray [0] = checkBoxPvrtc;
_combinationArray [1] = checkBoxEtc1;
_combinationArray [2] = checkBoxDxt15;
var tmp:uint = 0;
for(var i:int = 0;i<_combinationArray.length;i++){
    tmp = tmp|(uint(_combinationArray[i].selected)<<i);
}

if( tmp & selectedPvrtc){
    trace('selectedPvrtc')
}
if( tmp & selectedEtc1){
    trace('selectedEtc1')
}
if( tmp & selectedDxt15){
    trace('selectedDxt15')
}
```

Comment: thats what i was trying to do, works perfect haha... thank you @The_asMan